# How disable dynatrace for debug builds android

Tags: android, gradle, buildconfiguration, dynatrace, android-buildconfig

I want to disable dynatrace to collect debug builds

In my build.gradle (android):

```
dynatrace {
    configurations {
        debug {
            enabled false
        }
        release {
            enabled true
            autoStart {
                autoStart.enabled false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in tasks trace I see next

```
> Task :dynatrace:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :dynatrace:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :dynatrace:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :dynatrace:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :dynatrace:generateDebugResValues FROM-CACHE
> Task :dynatrace:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [acticle](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/operating-systems/android/instrumentation-via-plugin/configure-plugin-for-instrumentation/).
You have to create 2 separate apps in Dynatrace and use this config. After that your development data(debug) removes from the production data.

```
dynatrace {
    configurations {
        debug {
            variantFilter "[dD]ebug"
            autoStart {
                applicationId '<DebugApplicationID>'
                beaconUrl '<ProvidedBeaconURL>'
            }
        }
        prod {
            variantFilter "[rR]elease"
            autoStart {
                applicationId '<ProductionApplicationID>'
                beaconUrl '<ProvidedBeaconURL>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```